# need help identifying the bottleneck in hbase read performance

Tags: performance, hbase, bigdata

I am running some tests on hbase read performance, in particular how many GETS can a single region server support in our environment. The region server has 24 cores and 48G. We are running with a JVM heap of 8G and bucket cache (OffHeap) of 25G. The data served is entirely within the bucket cache.

Each client does a "list of hbase gets" continuously from with the entire keyspace, I was running 2 clients hitting the regionserver and noticed CPU usage of about 200%, with 4 clients it was around 400% and with 8 it was around 800%, however when i increased the number of clients to 16 the CPU hovered between 800 to 1000% (overall usage of about 40% CPU - 24 cores).

I dont think network and memory are the bottlenecks and I an not sure why hbase is not using more CPU with 16 clients.
[image: cpu]
[image: memory]
[image: network]
[image: top]

The peak around Friday 15:00 are tests with 8 clients, network was at 100MB/s
while peaks after Friday 18:00 are tests with 16 clints, network drops to ~75MB/s

we tried setting hbase.ipc.server.read.threadpool.size to 50 and hbase.regionserver.handler.count to 300.

Barring network/memory, i expected CPU usage to increase, however it doesnot. Any pointers to finding out the bottle neck would greatly help ? Is there some other parameter in hbase that could be tweaked ?

Comment: It's an interesting case. Could you shed some light at: 
    client does a "list of hbase gets" continuously from with the entire keyspace

Comment: i do a table.get(List<Get>), the list size is 2000, and the 2000 keys are chosen randomly from within the entire keyspace (4million rowkeys). Pseudo code  is   while (true) { List<Get> list = get2000KeysFrom4MKeyset(); table.get(list) }

Comment: Nothing unusual, total number of keys is small. I would look at hbase-specific metrics, using tcollector, for example.